# Inquiry to Voice Classification

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I'm a 24 male who is interested in vocal arts and have yet to receive any formal voice training.  But I would like to know my voice type. Attached are two audio clips of me descending from middle C to as low as I could and ascending from F4 to as high as I could (while trying not to break into falsetto).

1. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151715356814058&l=6528702054606550815
2. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151715360319058&l=3781106173026876953

   Apologies for the poor recording device and voice quality.

Answer (score 4):

**First, a disclaimer:** Labeling a voice type isn't something that is merely based on range - it's as much an issue of quality and agility (though admittedly less-so for male voices).  Beyond that, you're an untrained singer.  With training, not only would the extremes of your range likely extend, but the relative ease of singing in certain tessituras would be more evident.

That being said, based on your recordings, I think it's pretty safe to say you're a **tenor**.  It doesn't sound like you have many notes below C3, and the overall quality sounds tenorish to me.  Plus, the fact that you have a decent F4 and G4 without training is not at all typical of lower voice types.

Further training and diagnostic exercises would allow a voice teacher or vocal coach to make more specific qualifications.

Comment: Thank you for the great advice! I'm wondering if that last high note in my 1st clip is a falsetto? But it sounds neither chesty nor exactly falsetto when I sing it.

Comment: It sounds like it's wanting to slip into a new register, but I wouldn't call it falsetto.  It mostly just sounds tight and strained, and I think with some quality training you could have a really nice high Bb.

Comment: I see. I have just checked and it is D5. I can at most probably go a semitone/full tone higher than that in that same type of vocal production. On other hand, I notice that whenever I try to ascend from F#4/G4  onwards, there is prominent register change in my voice and I have some difficulty coordinating my voice (i.e. it might crack) when I descend from any notes above G#4 to G4.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense... I'm not near a piano to confirm what pitches you were singing.  A register break is normal around F#4 for the male voice.  Negotiating breaks is tricky for everyone and usually a large part of vocal training will focus on that.

Comment: What makes more sense? :P

Comment: I thought you were singing F4, G4, A4, and Bb4, not up to a D5.  So you were singing higher than I initially thought, which places the register breaks in the expected places and further confirms my guess that you're a tenor.

Comment: I see. You seem knowledgeable in voice. You sing as well:) ?

Comment: I'm a professional vocal coach/collaborative pianist.  I sing also, but not professionally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13212/discussion-between-alexy-vincenzo-and-munchywilly)

Comment: @MunchyWilly, welcome to Musical Performance & Practice.